# Toggle a menu after clicking one of its options in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, drop-down-menu

Currently I have a dropdown menu that I am using to allow a user to select a region. Once they click an option in the dropdown menu, I update the dropdown menu to reflect the region they selected. Upon clicking a menu option I also want the dropdown menu to toggle so that the dropdown options are no longer shown since a user has selected an option.

How would I go about doing this?

Component containing the dropdown menu

```
function RegionSelector (props) {
    var regions = [
        { 
          name:'Santa Cruz',
          id: '2958',
          spots:  
            [
                {name:'Steamer Lane', id:'4188'},
                {name:'Four Mile', id:'5023'},
                {name:'Waddell Creek', id:'5021'},
                {name: 'Mitchell\'s Cove', id:'5028'},
                {name: '26th Ave', id:'5030'}
            ]
        },
        { 
          name:'Los Angeles',
          id: '1234',
          spots:  
            [
                {name:'Newport', id:'1241'},
                {name:'HB', id:'3421'},
            ]
        }
    ]

    return (
        <div className="content col-xs-3 col-md-3">
            <div className="admin-panel">
                <label htmlFor="toggle" className="admin-text">
                    { props.selectedRegion === null ? 'Select Your Region' : props.selectedRegion.name}
                </label>
            </div>

            <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
            <label className="cog octicon octicon-gear" htmlFor="toggle"></label>
            <div className="menu">
                <div className="arrow"></div>
                    {regions.map((region) => {
                        return (
                            <a href="#" key={region.name} onClick={props.onSelect.bind(null, region)}>
                                {region.name}
                                <span className="icon octicon octicon-person"></span>
                            </a>
                        )
                    })}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

CSS for the dropdown menu:

```
.content
{
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.admin-panel
{
    background: #F8F8F8;
    width: 240px;
    height: 40px;
    color: #888888;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    font: bold 13px Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 41px;
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.2 );
}

.cog
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    border: none;
    color: #888888;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.admin-text:hover, .cog:hover { cursor: pointer; color: #555555; }

input#toggle { display: none; }
input#toggle ~ .menu { display: block; }
input#toggle:checked ~ .menu { display: none; }

.menu a
{
    display: block;
    background: #F8F8F8;
    width: 240px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    font: bold 13px Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.4 );
    line-height: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.2 );
}

.menu a:nth-child( 2 )
{
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}

.menu a:last-child
{
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

.menu a:hover { color: #555555; }

.menu a:hover > .octicon { color: #555555; }

.icon
{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #000000;
    color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.4 );
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.octicon-person { margin-right: 16px; }
.octicon-graph { margin-right: 11px; }
.octicon-cloud-upload { margin-right: 11px; }
.octicon-pencil { margin-right: 13px; }

.arrow
{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: 15px;
    border-left: 7px solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 9px solid #F8F8F8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using a function that returns JSX, but it looks like you might want to use a stateful component here. 
Then make sure the `regions` array is part of the state of the component. You can do this with something like this:

```
class RegionSelector extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
   setState({regions : [...]})
 }
  ....
```

Now in your onSelect function, just manually clear the region state.

```
function (onSelect) {
  this.setState({regions: []})
...
}
```

This will cause react to update the component, calling the render function again with the empty region array.

If you want to achieve this with a stateless component, your `regions` array has to be part of the state of the parent component that is instantiating your dropdown, and you have to do the same thing in `onSelect` to clear `regions`.

Comment: I agree with the approach of using a stateful component, that will probably be necessary unless I want to transition to a more standard dropdown instead of a custom design dropdown. However I don't want to remove the regions from the dropdown bar I just want to close it when the user selects a region. I want the user to be able to reopen it and change regions if they would like.

Comment: Is it bad practice to have a stateful component within another stateful component instead of passing the state down to that element